# Material UI Custom TextField state issue in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

A co-worker (more experienced in React than me) wrote this react wrapper component around mui's TextField control and it's not working as I'd expect, but I cannot figure out why. So I ended up creating a sandbox (link below) to use the native one to see if it worked and it does.

What I'm wondering is, why does the wrapper not display the data when the consumer component mounts, whereas the native mui text field does?. When Example.tsx loads, the native mui text field displays the data in the json as expected. And when you select English or Spanish, it displays what's in the state according to the selected language (and if there's no data for the language it displays blank, as it should).

The custom text field wrapper does not have this behavior. It starts out blank. It also doesn't display the data when you change languages either. I just started with React so I might be missing something, but I would at least expect this type of behavior to be the same.

You can comment out one or the other text fields in the sandbox to view them individually, if it makes it less confusing.

But here's the code of the wrapper component. Does anything stand out as being unusual or incorrect in terms of text field behavior in react?

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  TextField as MaterialTextField,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textField: {
    width: (props) => (props as TextFieldStyleProps).textFieldWidth + "px",
    "& input": {
      height: ".6rem"
    }
  }
});

export type TextFieldChangeHandler = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => any;

type TextFieldStyleProps = {
  textFieldWidth: number;
};

export interface TextFieldProps {
  id?: string;
  label: string;
  text: string;
  width: number;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onChangeHandler: TextFieldChangeHandler;
}

const CustomTextField = (props: TextFieldProps) => {
  const {
    label,
    text,
    width,
    onChangeHandler,
    disabled,
    id = "textFieldDefault"
  } = props;
  const classes = useStyles({ textFieldWidth: width });
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>(text);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    onChangeHandler(event);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Typography
          id={"text-field-label-" + label}
          component="label"
          htmlFor={id}
          variant="caption"
        >
          {label}
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <MaterialTextField
        id={id}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={classes.textField}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        size="small"
        value={value}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Link to codesandbox with example of the different behavior: [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-language-string-example-ulsu3)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the way your `customField` is set up, you have no way of controlling the state. you can only pass initial value to it. then the `value` state is declared inside the `customField` no longer listens to the changes of `text`. so when the parent component mounts the text value is an empty string which would be passed to the `useState` as initial value & the further changes are no longer reflected. one way you can fix this is by adding a useEffect for detecting changes of `text` & updating the value with it inside the `customField` component like this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(text);
  }, [text]);
```

[the working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-language-string-example-forked-4u1vm?file=/src/CustomTextField.tsx)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So basically the way this is set up, the only way to get text into it is to pass it once. And then it can only be changed by the keystrokes. I can't think of a reason why you'd want it this way, though. Probably just an oversight. Thanks a lot, really helped.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason either. With respect to your coworker, I gotta say It's just a weird design and an abstraction with no benefit, other than confusion. you either want a controlled component in which case you want to set the value to your local state variable (which you can't do here) or you want an uncontrolled component, in which case you don't have any need for keeping the value in a state & writing an onChange handler for it at all